# Why are you putting it so high?"

Tags: grammar

He threw the TV remote control.

I put it on a higher place.

> "Why are you putting it so high?"
>
> "Why are you putting it on the place so high?"

he said.

Can we ommit the "place"? Would it confusing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why are you **putting it up so high**?

or

> Why are you **putting it so high up**?

Either is fine.  ["High up"](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/high-up) works as either an adjective or an adverb, depending on the context.

However, a child may be more likely to ask:

> Why are you putting it **way up there**?

Comment: Nice addition, mentioning what a child might say.